# Blender: python batch/script to convert x3d format to obj format

Tags: python, object, blender, converters, x3d

In a Blender context, I am trying to convert an x3d file into an obj file format. To run the script I use the `command blender -b -P`. Here is the x3d file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="UTF-8"?>

    <X3D profile="Immersive" version="3.0">
      <head>
        <meta name="filename" content="/home/sim/Desktop/WebApp/pdeOnline/vEnv/pdeWeb/myStatic/Simu/field.x3d"/>
        <meta name="generator" content="Visualization ToolKit X3D exporter v0.9.1"/>
        <meta name="numberofelements" content="9"/>
      </head>
      <Scene>
        <Background skyColor="0.32 0.34 0.43"/>
        <Viewpoint fieldOfView="0.523599" position="1 1 6.29555" description="Default View" orientation="0 0 1 -0" centerOfRotation="1 1 0.5"/>
        <NavigationInfo type='"EXAMINE" "FLY" "ANY"' speed="4" headlight="true"/>
        <DirectionalLight ambientIntensity="1" intensity="0" color="1 1 1"/>
        <Transform DEF="ROOT" translation="0 0 0">
          <DirectionalLight direction="-0.111619 -0.766044 -0.633022" color="1 0.97232 0.90222" intensity="0.75" on="true"/>
          <DirectionalLight direction="0.0449435 0.965926 -0.254887" color="0.90824 0.93314 1" intensity="0.25" on="true"/>
          <DirectionalLight direction="-0.939693 0 0.34202" color="0.9998 0.9998 0.9998" intensity="0.214286" on="true"/>
          <DirectionalLight direction="0.939693 0 0.34202" color="0.9998 0.9998 0.9998" intensity="0.214286" on="true"/>
          <Transform translation="0 0 0" rotation="0 0 1 -0" scale="1 1 1">
            <Shape>
              <Appearance>
                <Material ambientIntensity="0" emissiveColor="0 0 0" diffuseColor="1 1 1" specularColor="0 0 0" shininess="0.78125" transparency="0"/>
              </Appearance>
              <IndexedFaceSet solid="false" colorPerVertex="true" normalPerVertex="false" coordIndex="
                0 1 2 3 -1 
                0 4 5 1 -1 
                0 3 6 4 -1 
                1 5 7 8 -1 
                1 8 9 2 -1 
                8 7 10 9 -1 
                4 11 12 5 -1 
                4 6 13 11 -1 
                5 12 14 7 -1 
                7 14 15 10 -1 
                11 13 16 12 -1 
                12 16 15 14 -1 
                3 2 17 6 -1 
                2 9 10 17 -1 
                6 17 16 13 -1 
                17 10 15 16 -1 
                18 19 20 21 -1 
                19 22 23 20 -1 
                24 25 26 27 -1 
                25 28 29 26 -1 
                30 31 32 33 -1 
                33 32 34 35 -1 
                36 37 38 39 -1 
                39 38 40 41 -1 
                " normalIndex="
                0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 ">
                <Coordinate DEF="VTKcoordinates0000" point="
                  0 0 0,
                  1 0 0,
                  1 0 1,
                  0 0 1,
                  0 1 0,
                  1 1 0,
                  0 1 1,
                  2 1 0,
                  2 0 0,
                  2 0 1,
                  2 1 1,
                  0 2 0,
                  1 2 0,
                  0 2 1,
                  2 2 0,
                  2 2 1,
                  1 2 1,
                  1 1 1,
                  0 0 0,
                  1 0 0,
                  1 0 1,
                  0 0 1,
                  2 0 0,
                  2 0 1,
                  2 0 0,
                  2 1 0,
                  2 1 1,
                  2 0 1,
                  2 2 0,
                  2 2 1,
                  0 2 0,
                  0 2 1,
                  1 2 1,
                  1 2 0,
                  2 2 1,
                  2 2 0,
                  0 0 0,
                  0 0 1,
                  0 1 1,
                  0 1 0,
                  0 2 1,
                  0 2 0,
                  "/>
                <Normal DEF="VTKnormals0000" vector="
                  0 -1 0,
                  0 0 -1,
                  -1 0 0,
                  0 0 -1,
                  0 -1 0,
                  1 0 0,
                  0 0 -1,
                  -1 0 0,
                  0 0 -1,
                  1 0 0,
                  0 1 0,
                  0 1 0,
                  0 0 1,
                  0 0 1,
                  0 0 1,
                  0 0 1,
                  0 -1 0,
                  0 -1 0,
                  1 0 0,
                  1 0 0,
                  0 1 0,
                  0 1 0,
                  -1 0 0,
                  -1 0 0,
                  "/>
              </IndexedFaceSet>
            </Shape>
          </Transform>
          <Transform translation="0 0 0" rotation="0 0 1 -0" scale="1 1 1"/>
        </Transform>
      </Scene>
    </X3D>
```

Here is the python script for the conversion. I use the `bpy` and `addon_utils` from three js library:

```
import os
            import bpy
            import addon_utils

            #https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2015/07/27/importing-blender-modelized-mesh-in-threejs.html
            # https://github.com/repsac/io_three

            def clear_scene():
                bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
                bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)

            def main(filePath, fileName):
                clear_scene()

                fullPath = os.path.join(filePath, fileName)
                bpy.ops.import_scene.x3d(filepath=fullPath)
                obj = bpy.data.objects[0]

                # find dimensions and scale accordingly
                #dims = obj.dimensions
                #scale = min( dims[0],  dims[1],  dims[2])

                # set cursor to world origin, and set object-origin the same
                #bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = (0, 0, 0)
                bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
                #bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='GEOMETRY_ORIGIN')
                #obj.scale = (scale, scale, scale)

                json_fileName =  fileName[:-3] + 'obj'
                finalPath = os.path.join(filePath, json_fileName)
                bpy.ops.export.three(filepath=finalPath)

            def ensure_addon():
                try:
                    addon_utils.enable(module_name="io_three")
                    return True
                except:
                    print('failed to enable io_three')
                    return False

            def path_iterator(path_name, ftype):
                for fp in os.listdir(path_name):
                    if fp.endswith(ftype):
                        yield fp

            if ensure_addon():
                filePath = "/"

                print("filePath" + filePath)

                for fileName in path_iterator(filePath, '.x3d'):
                    print(fileName)
                    main(filePath, fileName)
```

This is the error I receive:

```
RNA_def_property_ui_text: 'Non-skinning vertex groups to export (comma-separated, w/ star wildcard, BufferGeometry only).' description from 'option_extra_vgroups' '' ends with a '.' !
        RNA_def_property_ui_text: 'Index buffer type that will be used for BufferGeometry objects.' description from 'option_index_type' '' ends with a '.' !
        filePath/

        Blender quit
```

Can anyone point me out where I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please try to demonstrate some own research effort. Also please explain whether your problem is already on HelloWorld level of programming in Blender context or whether everything up to doing the actual format modification is clear to you.

Comment: You might want to ask this question on the [Blender StackExchange site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/).